# Regression with multiple observations of the independent variable for each dependent observation

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis

Let's say I have data where y is measured at some higher level than x. For instance y represents a State level outcome over time and x represents a county level data. (Additionally, the data is such that the State level outcome is not a natural aggregation of all county level outcomes.) Alternatively, y represents a subject outcome over time and x represents output from between 5 and 10 of his close friends.

You could run:
$y_{i,t}= \alpha + \beta \overline{x}_{i,t}+u_{i,t}$

However, there's no a-priori reason to believe that the response to all of the inputs is equal weighted.

You could run
$y_{i,t}=\alpha + \beta x_{i,j,t}+e_{i,j,t}$

Where each $y_{i,t}$ variable was duplicated for each level $j$. However this seems wrong to me, in part because it seems to induce a kind of errors-in-variables problem.

Can this be done, is there a better alternative, or is it a nonsensical way of thinking about the model?